# Digital input protection circuit

Tags: circuit-design, zener, circuit-protection, polyfuse

Can anyone explain to me how this circuit works?

I am familiar with the traditional Zener diode as voltage regulator (with a resistor,) but I couldn't tell what the fuse does here and why the 10K resistor is in parallel not in series.

[image]

Comment: As drawn, the circuit is incomplete. Depending on what it connects to and how that other circuitry operates, this can either do **nothing** or provide **some protection** in some cases. If I **assume** that "Arduino Din3" is an input that needs protecting, then that protection is **weak**. A 20 V pulse on "Din3" will blow the fuse but can still cause damage to the Arduino. If "Arduino Din3" is an input then a 10 k series resistor should be added.

Answer (score 1):

The PTC thermistor can be used as resettable fuses. They limit the current flow in the circuit. In this circuit it is in series with the input from the external world (Din3) to limit the current flow into the Digital Pin (Arduino_Din3).

Answer (score 0):

It is the overvoltage protection. When the voltage exceeds some value, drop voltage on input PTC resistor increases. PTC resistor get heated, resistance value increased and restrict current. So the voltage on digital input is not going above 5 volts. It protects also from negative voltage on input.